profile pictures for users in Django
Django has the built-in form called UserCreatioonForm for creating users. It has some fields like First and Last Name, Email, etc. But is it actually possible to have a field for uploading images which will be used as profile pictures for the user?
I tried to read about additional input fields on djangoproject.com/docs, but it was rather cryptic.

No, Django does not have a field for profile pictures. What you will do is you create a model that has a one to one relation with the User model and then you can use the image to you saved in that model.
models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
class Profile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', null=True, 
             blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

views.py -> uploading and updating profile
from .models import Profile
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
def upload_avatar(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile.avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar')
        profile.save()
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

profile.html


{% if request.user.profile.avatar %} 
<img  src="{{ request.user.profile.avatar.url }}" alt=" avatar-picture">
{% endif %}





t h a n k  y o u

@DishanthM on SO, there's no need to say "thank you". Instead, you should vote for questions and answers you find useful. If this answer solved your question, you should accept it using the v-shaped button to its left.
